# Hibernate 4 connection.autocommit=false ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, guice, guice-persist

We have an application using Java, hibernate 4, guice 3, guice-persist 3 on tomcat 6

connection.autocommit is configured to false in the hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="connection.proof_property">true</property>

    <!-- Disable second-level cache. -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>

    <!-- Print SQL to stdout. -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>

    <property name="id.new_generator_mappings">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and then re-create schema on SessionFactory build, for testing. -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Bind the getCurrentSession() method to the thread. -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- configuration pool via c3p0--> 
    <property name="c3p0.initialPoolSize">0</property>
    <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">32</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">100</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">0</property> 
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">600</property> <!-- seconds --> 

    <!-- Hibernate XML mapping files -->
    <!-- <mapping resource="org/MyClass.hbm.xml"/>-->

    <!-- Hibernate Annotations (and package-info.java)-->
    <mapping package="model"/>

</session-factory>
```

But on deployement, the logfile shows that autocommit is set to true:

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.9.Final}
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****, autocommit=true, proof_property=true, release_mode=auto}
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
28 janv. 2013 16:03:01 com.mchange.v2.log.MLog <clinit>
INFO: MLog clients using java 1.4+ standard logging.
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource getPoolManager
INFO: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@b6868296 [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@8d0e5680 [ acquireIncrement -> 1, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 1hgeby98szzd5hkbs91s5|a69b6b, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 0, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 600, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 32, maxStatements -> 100, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 0, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@d4b5ff9b [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hgeby98szzd5hkbs91s5|75b3ee, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev, properties -> {user=******, password=******, autocommit=true, proof_property=true, release_mode=auto} ], preferredTestQuery -> null, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> 1hgeby98szzd5hkbs91s5|1a9bea3, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000268: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
28 janv. 2013 16:03:02 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
```

Why hibernate is ignoring the autocommit property? And should we care? (as our tests shown us that an exception in a correctly annoted method does a rollback, so everything seems fine)

Comment: I think the property name should be renamed to `hibernate.connection.autocommit` instead of `hibernate.autocommit` in `hibernate.cfg.xml` per [javadoc C3P0](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/connection/C3P0ConnectionProvider.html)

Comment: When loading properties from hibernate.cfg.xml if the `hibernate.` is not at the beginning of the property it will prepend it so they certainly have the correct configuration key.  Also, if the property was getting missed entirely it should default to false.

Comment: I took your cfg.xml file verbatim and created a new project and it worked as expected, it logged true when I used the word "true" and false when I used the word "false".  So the issue is not in anything you have posted.  Put a breakpoint in `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(LoadedConfig loadedConfig)` and see what the value of the setting is at that point.  If it is not what you expect, see where it is getting the config from (crawl up the stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem when using hibernate + MySQL. Instead of set false but coming out true, I set it to true but it came out false. I saw your questions but there's no answer. I want to share how I solve the problem by:

1 restart the database server.

2 clean the project.

3 restart the web server.

I've tries so many ways, actually, I don't know why this finally worked... Just for sharing.

Comment: Might not be helpful, but I ended up using eclipselink and postgreSQL. PostgreSQL is way faster anyway.